# How to create hypertext link instead of button for Getpocket?

Tags: php, html, pocket

Could you please help me to create hypertext link for using Getpocket ?

Initially, I tried to put buttons on my website. But the problem is that I need to publish tens of buttons on the home of my web application. But then, it was loading extremely slowly and sometimes, the buttons were not showing up.

That's why I'm looking for an alternative, with the use of hypertext link instead.

I tried something like that without the javascript part but it wasn't working...

```
<a href="https://getpocket.com/save" 
   class="pocket-btn" data-lang="en" 
   data-save-url="http://yourDomain.com/the/page/to/save.html">
 Pocket
</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean its not WORKING ?

Comment: I arrive on the "save an item to pocket" page, without URL and title information of the page I wanted to save (https://getpocket.com/edit?url=&title=).

Comment: Why don't you just include the url and title in the link? (https://getpocket.com/edit?url=http://www.google.com&title=My+website)